# Pass mobile number to Facebook AccountKitActivity

Tags: android, facebook, account-kit

I am using [Facebook account kit](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/android/) to verify user mobile number. I have used below code,

```
final Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder =
            new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                    LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.TOKEN); // or .ResponseType.TOKEN
    // ... perform additional configuration ...
    intent.putExtra(
            AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
            configurationBuilder.build());
    startActivityForResult(intent, APP_REQUEST_CODE);
```

All is doing well. I want to pass user mobile number to AccountKit activity. Is it possible to make it work? How?
Actually I want to prevent duplicate mobile verification using Account Kit, is there any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in the place where it says

```
// ... perform additional configuration ...
```

you can set the initial phone number by doing:

```
configurationBuilder.setInitialPhoneNumber(phoneNumber);
```

where phoneNumber is of type com.facebook.accountkit.PhoneNumber. This class takes 3 parameters: country code (like "+1"), phone number (like "5551234567") and an ISO country code (like "US")

There's other settings you can do in configurationBuilder as well. See for reference: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/androidsdk/current/AccountKit/com/facebook/accountkit/ui/accountkitconfiguration.accountkitconfigurationbuilder.html/

Answer (score 8):

You can use this

```
PhoneNumber phoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("+880","16XXXXXXXX","BD"); // country code, phone number, country code 

 final Intent intent = new Intent(context, AccountKitActivity.class);
    AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new AccountKitConfiguration.AccountKitConfigurationBuilder(
                    LoginType.PHONE,
                    AccountKitActivity.ResponseType.CODE);

    configurationBuilder.setReadPhoneStateEnabled(true)
            .setReceiveSMS(true);

    intent.putExtra(
            AccountKitActivity.ACCOUNT_KIT_ACTIVITY_CONFIGURATION,
            configurationBuilder
                    .setInitialPhoneNumber(phoneNumber)
                    .build());
```